# sql server 2012 locked and wont function well

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-server-2012

After some time I get a weird behavior on my SQL Server 2012 database. Some queries wont run, queries which contain simple selects. Also queries to ALTER PROCEDURES wont run (they execute and then get stuck in the execution until I cancel them).

I ran a method to see which tables are locked and the only one I see is:

sysobjvalues    KEY (ec05837cd075)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                S Shared

This situation gets stabilized as soon as I restart the SQL Server service.

Some tables in the database allow SELECTs and some do not. I though that it was due some locks but the query to see locks wont show that any of my db tables are locked. What could be causing this weird behavior?

BTW: here is the query I run to get locks info:

```
    select  
        object_name(P.object_id) as TableName
        , resource_type
        , resource_description
        , request_mode
        , CASE REQUEST_MODE
                        WHEN 'S'        THEN 'Shared'
                        WHEN 'U'        THEN 'Update'
                        WHEN 'X'        THEN 'Exclusive'
                        WHEN 'IS'       THEN 'Intent Shared'
                        WHEN 'IU'       THEN 'Intent Update'
                        WHEN 'IX'       THEN 'Intent Exclusive'
                        WHEN 'SIU'      THEN 'Shared Intent Update'
                        WHEN 'SIX'      THEN 'Shared Intent Exclusive'
                        WHEN 'UIX'      THEN 'Update Intent Exclusive'
                        WHEN 'BU'       THEN 'Bulk Update'
                        WHEN 'RangeS_S' THEN 'Shared Range S'
                        WHEN 'RangeS_U' THEN 'Shared Range U'
                        WHEN 'RangeI_N' THEN 'Insert Range'
                        WHEN 'RangeI_S' THEN 'Insert Range S'
                        WHEN 'RangeI_U' THEN 'Insert Range U'
                        WHEN 'RangeI_X' THEN 'Insert Range X'
                        WHEN 'RangeX_S' THEN 'Exclusive range S'
                        WHEN 'RangeX_U' THEN 'Exclusive range U'
                        WHEN 'RangeX_X' THEN 'Exclusive range X'
                        WHEN 'SCH-M'    THEN 'Schema-Modification'
                        WHEN 'SCH-S'    THEN 'Schema-Stability'

            ELSE NULL
            END AS REQUEST_LOCK_MODE

    FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks   AS L
           join sys.partitions AS P 
            on L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like blocking.

When you experience this, look in the status bar of Management Studio ***for the query window where the query is hanging***. It will be in parentheses after your username, e.g.:

```
DOMAIN\Username (spid)
-----------------^^^^ this will be a number
```

Now, take ***that*** number, from within those parentheses, and open another window. In that second window, run the following:

```
SELECT blocking_session_id, wait_type 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE session_id = <SPID from above>;
```

If a session shows up in blocking_session_id, find out who they are and what they're doing.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE session_id = <blocking_session_id from above>;

DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<that blocking_session_id>);
```

You can also check if the database has any old transactions that haven't bee rolled back or committed, that may be causing an issue:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN();
```

Comment: (1) ran a query: select top 100 * from ContentToHashes (NOLOCK)
(2) SELECT @@SPID; shows 86.
(3) SELECT blocking_session_id, wait_type FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = 86, shows 
blocking_session_id wait_type
0 NULL
So I guess no locks on this session.

(4) also, DBCC OPENTRAN(); says "No active open transactions."

Comment: @Sagi PS `NOLOCK` is not a turbo button

Comment: What do you mean? if I remove (nolock) still same results. blocking session is 0, so no results for it.

Comment: @Sagi wait, what? Did you run the query that hangs before you ran SELECT @@SPID? If so, how is that possible? The latter result shouldn't be coming back if the former is hanging. You need to determine the spid *first* - I think you've checked for blocking on a spid that isn't doing anything.

Comment: @Sagi I know, I wasn't suggesting `NOLOCK` was causing the problem, which is why it was a comment, not an answer. I was just commenting that a lot of people use `NOLOCK` to speed queries up without understanding the consequences.

Comment: First ran the hanging query, while it is executing, opened a new window, ran @@SPID and got a number, for that number ran the sys.dm_exec_requests query and it returned one row with 0,null.

Comment: @Sagi Please go back and re-read. Again. You need to know the spid for the query that hangs. Opening a new window and pulling THAT spid is not going to help you at all, since that it is a different spid than the one is being blocked.

Comment: @Sagi The idea is to find the spid for the query that hangs, so as Aaron said, you need to run that part first. If you are running that query afterwards **and** getting a result, then the first query isn't hanging, so of course you get no blockings for it

Comment: Ok sorry. Now I see that it is index altering that gets the whole db stuck. 2013-09-04 20:00:00.820 suspended ALTER INDEX.
Did not think that ALTER index could cause this. What would you recommend doing?

Comment: Altering your index during off hours.

Comment: So basically you say that everytime I rebuild or reorganize my indexes it locks the tables involved?

Comment: @Sagi well, you can rebuild online if you have Enterprise edition, but otherwise a rebuild is an offline operation - users need to wait.

Comment: @Sagi That's exactly what is being said. Unless you have enterprise edition you want to rebuild during offline hours.